# Dimension of a vector space of functions

Tags: linear-algebra

> Where $S$ is a set, the functions $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ form a vector space under the natural operations: the sum $f+g$ is the function given by $(f +g)(s)=f(s)+g(s)$ and the scalar product is $(r\cdot f)(s) = r\cdot f(s)$. What is the dimension of the space resulting for each domain?
>
> **(a)** $S = \{1\}$ $\hspace{1mm}$ **(b)** $S = \{1,2\}$ $\hspace{1mm}$ **(c)** $S = \{1,...,n\}$

The result of my attempt at the problem is that the dimension in each case should be infinitely large. My reasoning is that the set of functions, in either **(a)**, **(b)**, or **(c)**, contains the space of $n$ degree polynomials functions $\mathscr{P}_n$, as any polynomial function takes values in all mentioned domains and returns a value in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathscr{P}_n$ has an infinitely large dimension, as $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ (the set of natural numbers) is infinitely large, the basis of the space containing $\mathscr{P}_n$ is infinitely large, and so must be the bases for the spaces in question. Therefore, the spaces in question have infinitely large dimensions.

However, the solution to the problem is

**(a)** dimension $ =1$

**(b)** dimension $ =2$

**(c)** dimension $ =n$

I see how the solutions apply to each case but my question is why? Where in my reasoning am I making a mistake? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Distinct polynomials can have the same values on $S$ and therefore induce the same function from $S \to \mathbb R$. For example, all polynomials $p$ satisfying $p(1) = 0$ result in the same function from $\{1\} \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you for the response Bungo. Can't you just apply the same logic and say all polynomials $p(1) =1$, $p(1)=2$, and so forth and still have an infinitely large collection of functions?

Comment: Of course. The dimension of a vector space isn't the same as its cardinality. For example, the vector space $\mathbb R^2$ has dimension 2 over $\mathbb R$ (any **basis** contains two vectors), but there are infinitely many vectors in the space, namely all linear combinations of the two basis vectors.

Comment: See if you can convince yourself that the set of all functions $S = \{1,2\} \to \mathbb R$ is actually the same thing as $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
For the general case $S=\{1,...,n\}$, prove that the functions $f_1,...,f_n$ defined as 
$f_i(i)=1$ and $f_i(j)=0$ for $i\neq j$, forms a basis.

In other words, show that $f_1,...,f_n$ are linearly independent and that for any function $g:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we can write $g$ as $\alpha_1f_1 + \alpha_2f_2 + ... + \alpha_nf_n$ for suitable $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$.

Answer (score 0):

How can a polynomial belong to those spaces? If you are talking about polynomial functions, then you are making a mistake. Consider, for instance, the polynomial functions $x^n$ ($n\in\mathbb N$). They are all distinct as functions from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$. *But they become all the same function if you restrict them to $\{1\}$!*

Comment: Thank you for the response José. I see your point, but can't you just take the polynomial functions $x^n + x^{n-1}$ and have another set of functions that are distinct on $\{1\}$?

Comment: @Andy When restricted to $S = \{1\}$, we have $x^n = x^{n-1}$ (they are the same function on the restricted domain), so $x^n + x^{n-1} = 2x^n$. In the same way, any function $\{1\} \to \mathbb R$ is a scalar multiple of $x^n$ restricted to $\{1\}$. In other words, the set consisting of the single function $x^n$ (or any other nonzero function $\{1\} \to \mathbb R$) constitutes a basis.